# XPath issue in Maven replacer plugin

Tags: maven, xpath

I get the following error when trying to use XPath to replace in web.xml with the Maven replacer plugin

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.2:replace (default) on project my-project: 
Error during XML replacement: Content is not allowed in prolog. -> [Help 1]
```

And here's the Maven code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId> 
    <version>1.5.2</version> 
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase> <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal> 
            </goals> 
        </execution> 
    </executions> 
    <configuration>
        <file>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
        <outputFile>target/web.xml</outputFile> 
        <regexFlags>
            <regexFlag>CASE_INSENSITIVE</regexFlag> 
        </regexFlags> 
<replacements> 
    <replacement>
        <xpath>/web-app/display-name</xpath>
        <token>.*</token> 
        <value>${project.name}</value> 
    </replacement> 
</replacements>
</plugin>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="my-project"
     version="2.5">

    <display-name>My Project</display-name>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: probably the "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" namespace. Apparently, according to https://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/wiki/TransformationConfiguration, you need to add         `<namespaceContexts><javaee>http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee</javaee></namespaceContexts>` in your plugin's `<configuration>` and then you can use `/javaee:web-app/javaee:display-name`

Comment: Yep, that was the case. Please add your comment as answer so I can vote it and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" namespace, and choose a prefix, let's say "javaee", and then use `/javaee:web-app/javaee:display-name` as your XPath expression.

According to this [link](https://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/wiki/TransformationConfiguration), you can do that in your plugin's `<configuration>` section:

```
<plugin>
    ...

    <configuration>
        <namespaceContexts>
            <javaee>http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee</javaee>
        </namespac‌​eContexts>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

"Content not allowed in prolog" either means the XML parser has found something other than whitespace characters, comments or processing instructions before the opening tag of the root element, or that there's characters before the `<?xml` (the XML declaration *must* be the first thing in the file, not even whitespace is allowed before it).

Check that the XML file does not have a byte-order mark at the start - certain editors (notably Windows notepad) have a habit of adding one to UTF-8 text files and I know this causes the XML parser in some versions of Java to choke.

Comment: Usually that's the case, but here the root cause is different.

Answer (score 0):

Select the *text node* you wish to replace entirely instead:

```
<replacement>
    <xpath>/web-app/display-name/text()</xpath>
    <token>^.*$</token> 
    <value>${project.name}</value> 
</replacement>
```

The replacer plugin does the following when working with xpaths that select a node:

1. Select the node (`<display-name>My Project</display-name>`)
2. Convert the entire node to a String (`"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><display-name>My Project</display-name>"`)
3. Replace the token (`.*`) in that String (String is now `"${project.name}"` - no more xml tags)
4. Parse the replaced String back into an XML Node: this breaks because your String is not valid XML (because you replaced it entirely.)

Easiest solution to this problem is to select the text node of the node instead.

Bonus: in this case, if your token is `.*` it will match twice (I'm not sure why) so make sure to use `^.*$` instead.